# regarding check for base sdk in application code

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I want to check if a particular device is having base sdk 5.0 or 4.3 or 4.2 or any other iOS sdk version. To put it more clearly, I want a particular code to run only and only if the iOS sdk version is 5.0 (using the APIs only supported in iOS 5) and if it is less than 5.0, then I want a different code to run. Does anyone has any idea about this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector` to check if the object has iOS version specified selector.

Comment: thanks wang, but what if I want to use device camera only if the base sdk is 5.0. If it is not 5.0, then I don't want to use the camera feature. How can I do this?

Comment: for example, `if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]) { /* this app is running on iOS 5 */ } else { /* iOS 4.3 and below */ }`

Comment: Hey wang, it will give me a compile-time error in base sdk 4.3 because if else condition will be executed at run time only, not on compile time. Right????

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting application properties in Xcode. Start reading [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/000-Introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000170i).